# How to replace row data in a table with row data from another table

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to replace the highlighted data in table A with the data in table B.

**I will show you the output must be.**
[image]

**Sample Output. I want to replace the *Large Fries with * DRNKS UPSL**

This is my code for highlighting the table row

```
$('#chainingBuild').on('click', '.clickable-row', function(event) {
          $('#chainingBuild tr').removeClass('selected');
         $(this).addClass('selected');
      $('#condimentsBuilderModal').modal('show');
    });
```

My Table B `html`:

```
<table  class="table table-striped table-bordered first_render" style="width:100%">
                <div class="content-noun" style="text-align: center;">
            <thead style="">
                <tr style="font-size:16px;">
                  <th>Noun Screen Name</th>
                  <th>Noun Price</th>
                  <th>Noun Image</th>
                  <th style="display:none;"></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
                </div>
            <tbody>
                @foreach($noun_table as $noun_data)
                    <tr id="nounClicked">
                        <td class="nounScreenNameClicked">{{$noun_data->menu_cat_screen_name}}</td>
                        <td>{{$noun_data->menu_cat_price}}</td>
                        <td class="nounScreenID" style="display:none;">{{$noun_data->menu_cat_id}}</td>
                        @if($noun_data->menu_cat_image == '')
                        <td></td>
                        @else
                        <td><img src="{{url('/storage/'.$noun_data->menu_cat_image.'')}}" style="height:110px; width:140px;" class="img-fluid"></td>
                        @endif
                    </tr>   
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
            </table>
```

Answer (score 2):

See below snippet

```js
$("#tableB td").click(
function(e){
   var tableBhtml =  $(this).closest('tr').html();
   // console.log(tableBhtml);
   
   $("#tableA tr.selected").html('');
   $("#tableA tr.selected").html(tableBhtml)
   
}
);
```

```css
table, table td{
border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

table td{
padding: 5px;
}
table tr:hover{
background: #f1f1f1;
}
table tr.selected{
background: blue; 
color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<b> TABLE A </b> 

<table id="tableA"> 
<tr>
  <td> Col 11 A </td>
  <td> Col 12 A </td>
  <td> Col 13 A</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Col 21 A </td>
  <td> Col 22 A </td>
  <td> Col 23 A</td>
</tr>
<tr class="selected">
  <td> Col 31 A </td>
  <td> Col 32 A </td>
  <td> Col 33 A</td>
</tr>
</table>

<b> TABLE B </b>

<table id="tableB"> 
<tr>
  <td> Col 11 B </td>
  <td> Col 12 B </td>
  <td> Col 13 B </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Col 21 B </td>
  <td> Col 22 B </td>
  <td> Col 23 B </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> Col 31 B </td>
  <td> Col 32 B </td>
  <td> Col 33 B </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Explanation:**

I have created two tables with ID `tableA` and `tableB`
in table we have a table row with class `selected`. You can place this class on any row as per your requirements and project flow.

Now in JQuery, i have written a code that only works on click event of `tableB td` or column. When we click on `tableB td`, it will fire and event. On click event, i have get the `closest()` tr html and stored html in a variable called `tableBhtml`. Then i have emptied the tableA selected TR and added `tableBhtml` into `#tableA tr.selected`  row